# VSCode Highlight Javscript Code in YAML Strings

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

I have YAML that looks like this:

```
name: foo
req: > 
  function () {
    ...
  }
init: > 
  function (event) {
    const bar = ['baz', 'foo']
    ...
  }
```

I would like to syntax highlight the JS that's in the YAML string. I'm using VSCode ATM but am open to using any other editor that makes this easier.

Looking at the VSCode page:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#injection-grammars

Injection grammars, especially the EMBEDDED LANGUAGES section, looks like what I want, but the instructions are a bit confusing.

Where do I put the `package.json`? Is source.js just for javascript? What would it be for yaml? How do I set the token to be the `>` to indicate the start of the embedded language and including everything under it that's indented?

Thanks.

Comment: you have to write an extension that defines these embedded sections, and then select the new languageID if you open such yaml file, or define/use the extension `.js.yaml`